# Learn GIS with Python

Tags: python, geolocation, geocoding, geospatial

I've been wanting to learn GIS, I already know lots of python, so I've been looking for online free sources to learn GIS.

Anyone one out there knows any good information to start with? tutorials? excercises?

Thank you!

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501008/find-current-geographic-coordinates-from-python-script

Comment: phooji, although that URL is intersting, it's not close to being a duplicate. Mauricio is asking abouth a whole scientific research area, not about specific scripts (as I understand it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youll be glad to know that there is a Stack exchange site dedicated to GIS ([Here](http://gis.stackexchange.com)), you could ask more specific questions there.

As for a specific answer to your very broad question - Have you got an idea what GIS Program do you plan to learn (do you plan on buying for yourself a full-cost program (which can be quite expensive)or have you got access to a full-cost in your work\studyplace or are you looking for a free-open-source (FOSS) program ??? Or do you want general "philosophical" writings on GIS (algorithms and such)?

I'll be glad to help, but "GIS" is a very broad subject (it's like asking a librarian a book about science...), so let's try to narrow your need down a bit.

Comment: Actually I would like to know more about GIS generalities. Im looking as well for a FOSS program to learn GIS scripting with python... I know GIS is a broad field, thats why I want to learn its generalities firts (algorithms and such) so that I can the see the specialized fields of it and choose the one I like the most. Ive heard a lot about opengeo and openstreetmap and others.

Comment: Mauricio, try this http://bit.ly/f0Vxoi - it's a introduction to GIS using Quantum GIS which is one of the leading FOSS's out there- it is one of the GIS programs that use Python the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can write python-Plugins for the free GIS [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Start with GDAL, then you won't be tied to some particular GIS and will learn to deal with data interchange for many GIS packages.

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole raft of Python APIs for all sorts of GIS proplems.  I suggest a good kick-off point for most of these has to be [OSGeo](http://www.osgeo.org/).  OSGeo is an organisation that promotes and maintains open source GIS tools of all sorts from desktop applications like QGIS or GRASS, through APIs like GDAL/OGR to web-mapping tools.

Most people, I guess start with GDAL/OGR as recommended above but you can add Shapely, Spatialite and PostGIS to that to get more comprehensive access to the full functionality of the GEOS library through Python.

A good over-view book on the subject is [Python Geospatial Development](https://www.packtpub.com/python-geospatial-development/book).  This book covers the most common Python APIs for GIS.

Answer (score 0):

A good introduction in [Python for GIS – A Personal Love Affair](http://gis-programming.com/?p=11)

Comment: That assumes the questioner is going to lay out $3K for an Arc licence.